# In "internet Linguistics" theory, does David Crystal include sociolinguistic patterns as affecting language changes?

Tags: language-change, sociolinguistics

I'm going to discuss language changes among social sites. I'm using internet linguistics as a theoretical framework, **but** one of my questions related to social aspect-gender... [internet linguistics](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Internet_linguistics) deals with internet as the main resource for language changes, but I am arguing that also social aspect can play a role in internet language changes. Does the theory of "internet linguistics" consider social aspects as causes for internet language changes?

Comment: I'm sorry, what is your question? Your title is couched as a question but I've read it three times and I don't understand what you are asking. And the text is not a question at all. Please edit it to make your question clearer.

Comment: I'm so sorry for these confusing details. .... My question: does the theory of "internet linguistics" consider  social aspects as causes for internet language changes?

Comment: Here what I find on your wiki page: The study of Internet linguistics can take place through four main perspectives: SOCIOLINGUISTIC, education, stylistics and applied linguistics.[1]. Is that not sufficient ?

Comment: you're right, but if you look to the content of sociolinguistic perspective, you can observe that nothing refer to social factors, like age and gender. I am confused if David Crystal means by this perspective the effect of social aspects or factors on language changes or not??